# Nested fragment menu action button only appears when i rotate the device

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu

I've got a [Xamarin, doubt it´s the thing to blame here though] support/v4 fragment that has 5 nested fragments on a ViewPager (With [this TabStrip implementation](https://github.com/LordZoltan/PagerSlidingTabStrip.Net)), out of which 4 must show an actionbar button to save their contents to disk. That´s working fine and dandy. My problem is that under certain configurations said actionbar button only appears from the second onCreate call onwards (IE: it starts working from the moment i rotate the device).

I have not managed to isolate the problem clearly but these are the clues i´ve got:

Device hints

- Nexus 5 / 5.1 - Working outright
- Samsung Galaxy Ace 3 / 4.2.2 - Working outright
- Samsung Galaxy Tab S / 4.4.2 - Working outright
- OnePlus One CM11S / 4.4.2 - Needs rotation
- Genymotion 10" / 4.4.2 - Needs rotation

Code hints

- The container/parent fragment calls setHasOptionsMenu(true) at onCreate, the same as all child fragments do
- No menu code does any distinction on whether savedInstanceState is null or not
- onCreateOptionsMenu is being called on all nested fragments on all activity re/creations and it does call back to base/super before inflating it´s own menu. It is being called after onResume, if that somehow helps.
- The menu file is not being overriden in any config (It is only present on the default menu/ folder)

Misc. comments:

- The parent fragment is the detail fragment on a drill-down/list-detail UI pattern, it replaces the list fragment (does not push it into the stack) that does have action buttons, those work fine. Except that when the detail fragment is replaced again with the list fragment, the list fragment is also missing it´s action button (Which, again, it had before being replaced by the detail fragment).
- I use action buttons extensively on other fragments that are also children of TabStrips, those work all the time.
- I am working on creating a minimal reproduction of this issue so i can share sample code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem stemmed from the fact that one of the child fragments was setting the activity title, possibly invalidating the menu.

Commenting out the setTitle(...) call solved the issue.